# Is there a way to send logs directly to google cloud logging using opentelemetry in a spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, open-telemetry, google-cloud-logging, open-telemetry-java

I am trying to send the application logs directly to google cloud logging using opentelemetry.

With the below changes, the logs are sent to OpenTelemetry collector which is up on port 4318

`pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

`logback-spring.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="com/google/cloud/spring/logging/logback-appender.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />

    <appender name="OpenTelemetry"
              class="io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.logback.appender.v1_0.OpenTelemetryAppender">
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="OpenTelemetry"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

How can I send those logs to google cloud logging instead of the Opentelemetry collector ?

Answer (score 0):

By using the `com.google.cloud.opentelemetry` library I am able to send the log/trace data directly to Google Cloud Log/Trace without using the Opentelemetry collector.

The developer is reponsible to create the span and end it when needed, for more information check [GoogleCloudPlatform example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/opentelemetry-operations-java/blob/main/examples/trace/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/opentelemetry/example/trace/TraceExporterExample.java)

The creation/end of the span can be centralized in 1 place by putting the relevant code in an interceptor.

- Spring framework way: create custom interceptor that implements `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor`
- Servlets way: create a custom interceptor that implements `jakarta.servlet.Filter` or `javax.servlet.Filter`